# Force set a string as an SELinux context of a file

Tags: selinux

I wonder if it's possible to **force set** a given string (e.g. `u:object_r:blah_blah_blah:s0)` as the SELinux context of a file.
Basically I'm going to root an Android x86 installation by placing files manually on a soft boot Ubuntu. However `chcon` doesn't allow me to set stuffs like `u:object_r:system_file:s0` because such a context is non-existent on Ubuntu. Actually I can use the `--reference-file=X` option but it would be better if I can manually type the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo setfattr -n security.selinux -v u:object_r:system_file:s0 'path/fileName'
```

you may need to install `attr` first and see [official docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/attr)